# module 'torch' has no attribute 'has_mps'

Tags: pytorch

I just followed a YouTube video that teaches how to install `PyTorch` nightly for MacBook to accelerate by M1 chip. However, I came across a  really weird problem. I can see in the jupyter notebook that `torch.has_mps = True`. But in jupyter notebook in vscode, it shows that module `torch` has no attribute `has_mps`.

Can anyone kindly tell me why? really confusing.

Answer (score 7):

Just make sure you installed the nightly build of PyTorch.
Apple Silicon support in PyTorch is currently available only in nightly builds.

e.g., if you're using conda, try this:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch-nightly
```

or with pip

```
pip3 install --pre torch torchvision --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu
```

See more here:

https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

The script to verify that you're using the correct version is like you write, you can simply open python REPL in your env where you installed the above:

```
import torch
torch.has_mps
```

And you should get

```
True
```

To select the device, use "mps" instead of "cuda" (what you see in tutorials):

```
device = "mps" if torch.has_mps else "cpu"
print(f'Using device: {device}')
```

P.S. Although the guide suggest to install `torchaudio`, it will not work, at least with `conda` environments.

P.P.S. Also, try with the environment in this github repo:

`https://github.com/causevic/mlboxm1/blob/main/pytorch_mac_m1.yml`

Comment: If this does not work for you where would you start debugging? I created a new environment and followed exactly these steps immediately afterwards and get AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'has_mps'

Comment: I would double check if the correct virtual environment is activated. Also, make sure it’s nightly build you’ve installed and not the latest official one.

Comment: It's nothing obvious like that. I was able to install outsde of a conda environment and that fixed the problem but it seems strange it cannot install into a conda environment

Comment: When you do the pip install from above, check the output. It sometimes falls back to the official channel. I mean, if it worked with global python, it should also work with conda. Try this: conda update pytorch torchvision -c pytorch-nightly

Comment: I have edited the answer to point to a github repo with a env yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are using a MacBook but for general use cases, see this link in which `PyTorch` has provided a tool that you can select your system components and it will give you the correct version of `PyTorch` to be installed. Here is the link to the tool: [PyTorch Tool.](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)

In your case you would have to run:

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

This comes from me selecting `OS=MAC, Package=Pip, Language=Python` and it gives you the above command. You can obviously change the system, language, package manager, etc.

For general use cases, here are a couple of things to keep in mind when using `PyTorch` locally (on your laptop/pc):

- Currently, `PyTorch` on Windows only supports Python 3.8 to 3.11 (Python 2.x is not supported)
- You always need to consider what OS, package manager (`pip, conda`), `cuda` (if you have or not) and language (Python, C++, Java) you are using.

Comment: first answer didn't work but this did. thank you